# Use php include within a php code

Tags: php

I have a php code that will create a txt file, the problem I'm having is adding is the content of the txt file.

I want to include it from an external file.

This is the code i have used so far:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST;
$time = time();
$filename_prefix = 'file/evidence_file';
$filename_extn   = 'txt';

$filename = $filename_prefix.'-'.$time.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$filename_extn;

if( file_exists( $filename ) ){
 # EXTREMELY UNLIKELY, unless two forms with the same content and at the same time are submitted
  $filename = $filename_prefix.'-'.$time.'-'.uniqid().'-'.uniqid().'.'.$filename_extn;
 # IMPROBABLE that this will clash now...
}

if( file_exists( $filename ) ){
 # Handle the Error Condition
}else{
  file_put_contents( $filename , '<?php include("text.php"); ?>' );
}
?>
```

The problem is using the php include within the current code! All that it prints in the txt file is:

```
<?php include("text.php"); ?>
```

How can I get it to display the content of text.php?

Also the text.php file contains php code.

Comment: file_get_contents() instead of include()

Comment: Do you want to execute the php file as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said, you can use file_gets_content to get the content of the file.

But if you want to first execute the file, as it's php code, and get the **resulting content** and put in the file then (I guess it's what you want), you have to use the buffer :

```
ob_start();

include('text.php');

$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents($filename , $content);
```

This way, the php file is executed and it's resulted content is passed to the file.
If you want to know more about ouput control functions, here's the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you're just putting in a string to the [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents), so it will take what you put in literally, and anyway, `include()` isn't what you want anyway

`include("text.php");`  loads the php file and execute its contents when put inside PHP, I don't think you want to do that. Use `file_get_contents()` instead, like this:

```
file_put_contents($filename,file_get_contents("text.php"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should do it like that

```
file_put_contents( $filename , '<?php '. file_get_contents("text.php") .'?>' );
```

`file_get_contents` function returns the file contents **as a string** while `include` literally **includes and evaluates** the file. Since your file is a PHP file and you only want to include it as a string my solution should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) function instead of include.

```
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents("text.php"));
```

Use `include` when you want the included code to be executed, not used as a text.

Comment: You should add code to explain how to use `file_get_contents` (along with the explanation), perhaps explain why `include` isn't appropriate in this use case scenario, otherwise this is more of a comment than an answer. Edit: Better